# Colors wrong on Canon TS6020 printer in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, printing, canon

I am a 75 great grandmother that just installed Linux Mint in her old lap top. I refused to continue with the almost daily up`dates and crashes.

Everything is going well except I cannot get my [Canon TS 6020](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/ts-series-inkjet/ts6020-black/pixma-ts6020) printer to print colors correctly. I cannot find the printer window to set up the correct group: CMYK

I might need to find calibration and profiling software.

Thank you for all the help and tips you can provide. Have a wonderful day with many blessings.

Comment: https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/ts-series-inkjet/ts6020-black/pixma-ts6020?tab=drivers_downloads has the drivers; use Debian drivers for Mint.  Did you follow this procedure for the printer install (allowing for the different model with different drivers) https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=246120&p=1319872&hilit=Canon+inkjet+color#p1319872 ?